# Adding country flag to pickerinput shinywidgets

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

There is a example how to add country flags to `checkBoxGroupInput` here

https://gist.github.com/bborgesr/f2c865556af3b92e6991e1a34ced2a4a

I am trying to adjust the code slightly to achieve the same result using `pickerinput` from shinywidgets. However, in my results I do not see any image.

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)

  countries <- c("Australia", "United Kingdom", "United States")

  flags <- c(
    "https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/au.svg",
    "https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/gb.svg",
    "https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/us.svg"
  )

  ui <- fluidPage(

    pickerInput("countries", "countries", multiple = T,
                choices = countries,

                choicesOpt = list(content =  
                                    mapply(countries, flags, FUN = function(country, flagUrl) {
                                      tagList(
                                        tags$img(src=flagUrl, width=20, height=15),
                                        country
                                      )
                                    }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

                                    ))
    ,

  textOutput("txt")
  )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$txt <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", paste(input$countries, collapse = ", "))
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi you don't want to add options as tagList but rather as HTML strings like this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

countries <- c("Australia", "United Kingdom", "United States")

flags <- c(
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/au.svg",
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/gb.svg",
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/us.svg"
)

ui <- fluidPage(

  pickerInput("countries", "countries", multiple = T,
              choices = countries,

              choicesOpt = list(content =  
                                  mapply(countries, flags, FUN = function(country, flagUrl) {
                                    HTML(paste(
                                      tags$img(src=flagUrl, width=20, height=15),
                                      country
                                    ))
                                  }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

              ))
  ,

  textOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$txt <- renderText({
    paste("You chose", paste(input$countries, collapse = ", "))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Barton It did help, thanks. A question though, is it possible to remove the country name and keep just the flag, but include options = list(`live-search` = T) and search for "Australia" for example and have the flag show up?