# How to have choices of `selectInput()` as elements from a data frame which are pasted together, separated by "|" and aligned?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame of two columns and several rows. I want each row of the data frame to be represented as a choice in a `selectInput()`. The two elements of each row are supposed to be separated by `|`. These separators should be exactly one below each other in the `selectInput()`. Furthermore, when a choice is selected only the first element corresponding to the first column should be shown.

My idea was to use the number of chars to achieve the alignment. However, different chars have different sizes. That's why this appraoch unfortunately doesn't work. See the following example.

```
library(shiny) 
library(stringi)

a <- c("Veronica", "Paul", "Elisabeth", "Mike", "Katy", "Tim")
b <- c(50015, 23010, 86812, 55497, 32309, 67631)
data <- data.frame(a, b)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selectID", 
              label = "Test Label:", 
              choices = as.list(c("", paste(data[, 1], stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), max(nchar(data[, 1])) - nchar(data[, 1])), "|", data[, 2]))))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Additionally, when I select the first row for example, only `Veronica` should be shown. At the moment, I do not have an idea how to achieve this.

By the way, I saw this kind of dropdown menu in an Access database. So maybe shiny or a shiny related package offers this kind of functionality and I just didn't find it. In any case, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.  To display a different value to the selection of a `selectInput`, you have to *name* the elements of the `choices` vector.  The padding doesn't show up inside the dropdown because the default behaviour of HTML is to collapse white space.  So you need to tweak the CSS that formats the dropdown.  That's what the `tags$head(...)` is for.

I've tidied up your derivation of the choice list and added a `textOutput` to demonstrate the difference between the items displayed by the `selectInput` and its return value.

```
library(shiny) 
library(stringr)

a <- c("Veronica", "Paul", "Elisabeth", "Mike", "Katy", "Tim")
b <- c(50015, 23010, 86812, 55497, 32309, 67631)
data <- data.frame(a, b)
maxWidth <- max(str_length(data[, 1]))
choiceList <- data[, 1]
names(choiceList) <- paste0(str_pad(data[, 1], width=maxWidth, side="right"), "|", data[, 2])

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".option {font-family: Monospace; white-space: pre; }")),
  selectInput("selectID", 
                label = "Test Label:", 
                choices = choiceList
                ),
    textOutput("selection")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$selection <- renderText({ input$selectID })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]
[image]

Note that the derivation of the choices for the `selectInput` is static. If you want that to be dynamic, you need to move the code to populate it inside the `server` function and wrap it in an `observe` or `observeEvent`.  You'd probably need to make `data` reactive as well.

**Edit: dealing with proportional fonts**

The link in my comment below gives the key to a solution using `shinyWidgets`.  My guess that using `tags$span()` would help was wrong because all the arguments to `tags$span()` are taken as the content of the tag rather than as arguments to the tag.  So we need to construct the necessary HTML manually.

For convenience, I've added the a variable containing the necessary HTML to the data frame.  The `rowwise()` is necessary to limit the concatenation to the current row rather than the entire data frame.  I assume that the "|" separator is no longer required.

Pick the width of the `col1` class to be "long enough" or calculate it on the fly.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

a <- c("Veronica", "Paul", "Elisabeth", "Mike", "Katy", "Tim")
b <- c(50015, 23010, 86812, 55497, 32309, 67631)
data <- data.frame(a, b) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dropdownText=HTML(paste0("<span class='col1'>", a, "</span><span class='col2'>", b, "</span>"))) %>% 
  ungroup()

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(".col1 {min-width: 150px; display: inline-block; }"),
    tags$style(".col2 {min-width: auto;  display: inline-block; }")
  ),
  pickerInput("selectID", 
              label = "Test Label:", 
              choices = data$a,
              choicesOpt=list(content=data$dropdownText)
  ),
  textOutput("selection")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$selection <- renderText({ input$selectID })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There are undoubtedly better (ie more precise) ways of specifying the CSS classes and selectors, but I don't know enough CSS to know what they are.

[image]

**Edit 2**

To display only the first column in the `selectInput` but both columns in the dropdown, change the `tags$head()` to

```
  tags$head(
    tags$style(".col1 {min-width: 150px; display: inline-block; }"),
    tags$style(".col2 {min-width: auto;  display: inline-block; }"),
    tags$style(".filter-option-inner-inner .col2 {min-width: auto; 
               display: inline-block; visibility: hidden; }")
  )
```

The third element overrides the visibility of elements styled with the`col2` style when they are children of elements with the `filter-option-inner-inner` style.  You can see how various elements of the UI are styled by opening the app in a browser, right-clicking anywhere on the page and selecting "Inspect" or similar.

[image]

Comment: Ah.  I've just noted your comment about the alignment of the separators in the dropdown list.  Sorry.  That's trickier with a proportional font.  Are you willing to use a monospace font?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like to have proportional font. Do you have an idea how to achieve this? And could you please be a bit more precise about the last paragraph?

Comment: Alignment is difficult when using a proportional font because counting characters and padding with spaces is no longer sufficient.  You need to use HTML and/or CSS to get the alignment.  I don't know how to pass HTML to a `selectInput`.  However, the `showContent` parameter to `pickerOptions()` in the `shinyWidgets` [package](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets) makes me think `shinyWidgets::pickerInput` has possibilities...

Comment: Yes.  I reckon you could adapt the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741321/adding-country-flag-to-pickerinput-shinywidgets) to get what you want, using  a couple of `tags$span`s in place of the `tags$img` in the defintion of `choicesOpt`.  Once you figure out the right HTML/CSS, of course...

Comment: That's a very nice solution, thanks a lot. Do you think it's possible to show only the first column entry after the selection? For example, when the first choice is selected, only "Veronica" is shown but not "50015".

Comment: See edit 2 above.  You wrote "... could you please be a bit more precise about the last paragraph?".  Which last paragraph?  I've lost track...

Comment: Edit 2 is exactly what I meant. Thank you very much. I am aware of the "Inspect" feature but it seems to me that one needs to know a little HTML and CSS to use it. So you helped me a lot.